# Add URL to entire photo

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, wordpress

I am using a plugin called Distinctive Portfolio on my Wordpress site.  On [this page](http://pjstagingdecorating.com/interior-decorating-projects-level-2/), when you hover over a photo, I simply want to get rid of the tooltip (which is garbled), icon (which is supposed to be a link image but doesn't appear) and make the entire photo clickable.  Image of what currently happens when I hover over the photo is below. Am hoping for a CSS solution but if not I can go into the plugin and play around. Please help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:none;` to the class `.dtp-icon-wrapper`

```
.dtp-icon-wrapper {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: hsl(0, 100%, 100%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: none;
}
```

Works fine , the icon does't show anymore.

To make the whole image clickable(and if your in control of the HTML) , wrap the following element:

```
<div class="view">

</div>
```

inside a `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Solonik.   Yes, but I also want the whole photo to be clickable.  I removed the icon--I knew how to do that--but now there is no link on the photo.

Comment: That is, the `a href` is within the div for `dtp-icon-wrapper urllink`.   I want to move it with css or Javascript so that it applies to the whole image.